# Suitable small bottle for liquid

Tags: bottle

I need to find a leak proof glass bottle for some liquid, which I would later put into the refrigerator. And because I tend to put it horizontally, I would prefer to use a leak proof bottle which is cheap and easy to get.

I considered the glass bottle for some juice in store but I do not trust the simple metal screw lid. I don't trust cork too.

I know ikea has the slom bottle but they only come in 1L size, it would be too large. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Mason jars are your friend.  You can buy them at Wal-Mart by the dozen, they are leak-proof and easy to sanitize.  They come in a variety of sizes as well.  Mason jars are used to can fruit preserves (among other things) in a completely *sterile* manner (which is beyond *sanitary*).  Screw-on lids will give you plenty of protection, especially if you steam-pressure sterilize, or use your regular brewing sanitizer!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a plastic screw like the ones that come in soft drink bottles?

Any reason for not trusting the metallic ones? Fear of leaking or corrosion?

Answer (score 0):

Googling gave me this.

[http://www.amazon.com/Small-Bottle-Convenient-Square-Leakproof/dp/B000NWYUW4](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000NWYUW4)

Its nice and square so its all stacky and such. Seems nice for a fridge. Not sure if you find it cheap or not however.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used this company, but they seem to have every conceivable bottle ever imagined.

http://www.containerandpackaging.com/catalog/glass-bottles/13/

I am assuming that you are in USA.

If you are from South Africa, then go to www.consol.co.za.